# Uninstall ubuntu in a strange manner

Tags: boot, uninstall, hardware, live-usb, format

I have failed by the installation of kali linux and remove windows. instead I installed Ubuntu 13.04.

I have a boot-able USB with windows 7, but I cant boot from it. My question is, can I uninstall ubuntu without re-formatting the hard-drive manually?

Comment: Yes, you can choose **Replace ... with Ubuntu** in the Ubuntu installer and the Ubuntu installer will allocate the entire disk for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You dont't have to re-formatting your hard-drive. If you have unpacking the img file of Windows 7 on a USB drive you can decide to delete the whole hard-drive by installing windows 7.

Make sure you have change the boot order and your bios have aktivated removable divise.
The other methode is to aktivate the boot menu while the computer is booting.